# After restoring magento2 from backup file, frontend design is broken, not loading CSS and JavaScript

Tags: magento2, javascript, error, css

I think I tried all the suggested method. But not working.

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I also deleted cache, changed permission of pub/static to 777.
Nothing did help.

Admin login page design is also broken. But once logged in, then everything looks fine.

On the browser, error message says, **"404 not found**" and "**Script from [URL] was blocked due to mime type mismatch**" for the css and javascript files

What could be wrong?

Comment: are you getting any error ? Check in `core_config_data` table that your css or js are merged or not?

Comment: in system log, nothing.  Also nothing in the error_log of the root folder.

Comment: Try deleting these directories: `pub/static/frontend/` and `var/view_preprocessed` and then run the static-content:deploy command again.

Comment: tried that, but also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason.

When you restore from backup of the filesystem_code, it doesn't create **update** folder at the root.

The previous magento installation which crashed still had the **update** folder, so I copied this folder to the newly restored folder.

Also make sure to have /pub/static.php, /pub/static/.htaccess and /var/.htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling static content versioning:

From your MySQL:

```
update core_config_data set value=0 where path='dev/static/sign';
```

Then from CLI:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Sometimes, do not ask me why, it simply fails and disabling content versioning fixes it.

Comment: unfortunately this didn't help.

Comment: error message on the browser says, "404 not found" and "Script from [URL] was blocked due to mime type mismatch" for the css and javascript files

Comment: Is the URL correct? Can you paste here an example?

Comment: sure, for example, http://mystore.com/pub/static/frontend/my/theme/ja_JP/css/styles-m.css

Comment: Seems correct. Are you sure you have the same server config?

Comment: server config? what do you mean?

Comment: I mean your webserver config

Comment: what exactly do I need to check on webserver?